# is it necessary to store_result after UPDATE prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I wrote a queryHandler function which looks like this
and this function is only called on UPDATE queries.

```
if ($stmt = $db->prepare($query)) {

        $bind = $this->refValues($data);
        array_unshift($bind, $variableType);

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $bind);

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

    } else {
        return 'MYSQL QUERY ERROR - Prepared Statement';
    }

    return true;
}
```

is it necessary to call the method store_result or is it okey to just, close the statement after execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is okey to just close, as stated in [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php)

> `mysqli_store_result()` returns `FALSE` in case the query didn't return a
>   result set (if the query was, for example an `INSERT` statement).

Comment: If this answer your question, you should accept it as best answer.